# jquery submit url query strings without form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this simple html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
             var selectval = $('select').val();
             $.get('/',
             {
                  selectval: selectval
             });
         });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <select>
         <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
         <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    </select>

    <button>Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the button to act like a submit button on a form with get method. So clicking the button should submit the get variable (selectval) as a query string.

So clicking the button should go to:

```
http://domain.com/?selectval=option1
```

Is there a way to do this without wrapping into a form?

Comment: you should ids to the elements

Comment: Why don't you want to wrap into a `form`?

Comment: i don't like using forms much. Also interested to know if this is doable at all or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
             var selectval = $('select').val();
             location.href = "?selectval="+selectval;
         });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: :) Sometimes solutions are simpler than our expectations.  Why should we try harder way? :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it and it is perfectly valid to do so. You can try the following method to do it. Note I have used IDs for the required elements.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#btn').click( function(){
             var selectval = $('#opt').val();
             $.get('/',
             {
                  selectval: selectval
             },function(data){
                 alert(data);
             });
         });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <select id="opt">
         <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
         <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    </select>

    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dhsvex7s/)

Comment: sorry tried this and it did nothing...it didn't submit anything

Comment: It is working for me, the only thing i changed is use jquery from different source. `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"` `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` doesn't seem to load from my machine